# How to show Password till the button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have created a `Password` input field, and a `button`, when you click on the button, it shows the password in `Text Format`.

The problem is that, it does not hide it again, I want the password to be shown till the button is pressed, when user un-touch the button, it should go back to the original password `dotted` mode.

I have written the following code, Its changing `Dotted password` to text, but not changing `text` to `dotted-password`.

```
 tvEmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (tvEmail.getRight() - tvEmail.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    return true;
                }
            }else{
                tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD );
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (tvEmail.getRight() - tvEmail.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD );
                    return true;
                }
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I believe you `ACTION_OUTSIDE` should be `ACTION_UP`

Comment: `ACTION_UP` is also not changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
passwordShown = false;

tvEmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(event.getRawX() <= (tvEmail.getRight() - tvEmail.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    passwordShown = true;
                    return true; 
                } 
            } 
            else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                      event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL ||
                      event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) && passwordShown) {
                tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
                passwordShown = false;
                return true; 
            } 

            return false; 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: This is also not changing the text into password

Comment: This is now just displaying password, and not converting it into text

Comment: @Kirmani88 added motion events `ACTION_CANCEL` and `ACTION_OUTSIDE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
 tvEmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
             @Override 
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                 {
                     tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                     return true; 
                 } 
                 else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                     tvPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                     return true; 
                 } 
                 return false; 
             } 
         });
```

// Considering tvEmail is either Button or TextView, hence above code can help you in achieving the functionality you want